# Add a word in php code

Tags: php, echo

in this code, I need to add a simple text "from" after the calendar icon. 
How can i do?

Thank you

```
$html .= '<span class="dashicons dashicons-calendar"></span>' . $datetime->date_range( $date_format ) . '<br/>';
```

Comment: same way you did for `. '<br/>'`

Comment: *"Add a line text in php code"* - adding a line means just that; "adding a line". What you meant to say was to "add a word".

Comment: @MarcoGentili Where is the problem now?

Comment: @Rizier123, I mean fixed the title of question. I need to add the word "from" after the icon. Thank you

Comment: I answered this less than a minute after you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$html .= '<span class="dashicons dashicons-calendar"></span>'.'From'. $datetime->date_range( $date_format ) . '<br/>';
```